# Adding tab bar Item without View Controller

Tags: uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible to create `UITabBarController` with Tab bar items that don't have views associated to it?
I need this because I will custom the function of the tab bar item, such as showing `UIActionSheet` on click of the tab bar item instead of showing a view.  please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You WILL have to associate each Tab to a Controller.

Options that you have:

1. Associate a Controller to the Tab. In the `viewWillApear:` method, present the `ActionSheet`.
2. Use ToolBar instead of Tabbar. Thus you can completely control the selection of options.

Comment: If I will use Options 1, How can I associate a controller to the tab? Do you mind to post sample code?

Comment: Please check these Sample tutorials for using UITabbarController.      **1. Programtically:** http://simplecode.me/2011/12/05/tab-based-ios-apps-uitabbarcontroller/  
**2. Using XIB:** http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2012/09/tabbed-application-using-interface.html